# Download button not working, file not found

Tags: html

I'm trying to place a button that, when clicked, downloads the file aaa.txt.

I have that file on the same folder as my index.html.

I've tried this:

```
<a href="aaa.txt" download>aaa</a>
```

```
<a target="_blank" href="aaa.txt" download>aaa</a>
```

```
<a href="aaa.txt" download class="download-btn">aaa</a>
```

But none seem to work. When clicked, chrome downloads a aaa.htm and says "error:file not found"

Also, I'm on a private server, not just running the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple you just need to specify the route more accurately, by adding a forward slash "/" before aaa.txt

```
    <a href="/aaa.txt" download>aaa</a>
```

for more info, you can refer [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_download_link.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It deepens from where you generate the link:

```
/  = root of the current app (/);

./ = current directory (/subfolder/subfolder/);

../ = parent of the current directory (/parentFolder/).
```

Means if you have only a index.html file in root then you need only `/filename.ext`. In your case:
aaa